# Calculate the components of a unit vector that lies in the xy-plane and makes equal angles with the positive directions of the x- and y-axes

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

It's just a doubt.

$\vec { A } = A \hat{ x }  + A\hat { y} $

$ A\hat { y} =A\hat{ x} $

$\vec { A } = A \hat { x }  + A\hat { x} $

Now finding the magnitud of the vector,

$A=\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } $

So the components of the unit vector are:

$\vec { A } = \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \hat { x } +\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 } } \hat { y} $

Is my answer right?

Comment: No, it is not because the length of your vector is not 1. The "halves" should be under a square root

Comment: You seemed to have made some typing mistakes. The desired unit vector is  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{y}$. The notations used are also not the standard ones. For example, what is meant by $\hat{A} = 1$?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. 

And as for imanfat I think there was a misunderstanding  the vector is not one. But the unit vector is.

Comment: about $A\hat =1$ I was just remarking that the value of a unit vector was 1.

Comment: Anyway ,I would like to know  having already fixed my mistakes in the post; If my answer for this problem is right.

Comment: @imranfat $\sqrt{1\over b} = {\sqrt{1}\over \sqrt{b}} = {1\over\sqrt{b}}$

Comment: The final answer is correct (at this time when I'm reading it). The solution, however, contains many serious errors stemming from your not understanding what a vector is. For example, a statement saying "$\text{vector}=\text{number}$" is a meaningless one. So is the phrase "a unit vector is equal to one", for the same reason.

Comment: @zipirovich I  really don't understand what you mean about vector=number. I never did such thing and as for the unit vector I was just emphasising its value.but i have just edited and deleted due it was really meaningless.

Comment: It's still hard to understand your solution. You could start by explaining your notation: what are $\vec{A}$, $A$, $\hat{x}$, and $\hat{y}$? I'm pretty sure that $\vec{A}$ stands for a vector (that we need to find). But then what are those other three things?

Comment: Also, when I visited this page before, you had a correct answer $\vec{A}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{y}$ here. Well, it's correct assuming $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ stand for the coordinate unit vectors in the directions of the respective axes, although I'm not quite sure about your notation. (By the way, note that there's also a second answer to the question.) But now for some reason it has been reverted to an incorrect $\vec{A}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{x}+\frac{1}{2}\hat{y}$.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I forgot to put the squareroots .
Thanks...