# How do I Calculate the components of a unit vector that lies in the xy-plane and makes equal angles .....

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, mathematical-physics

Calculate the components of a unit vector that lies in the xy-plane and makes equal angles with the positive directions of the x- and y-axes

Comment: What have you tried? [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) a link to help you write a better answer that can give you more reputation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407141/calculate-the-components-of-a-unit-vector-that-lies-in-the-xy-plane-and-makes-eq?noredirect=1#comment4968926_2407141

Comment: There is what i have done

Comment: But I realized I was wrong and  don't know how to work it out.

Comment: Your method more or less is correct - however I have a shorter and more simple answer to the question.

Comment: Help me please...

Comment: You have asked this question before without referencing to the first one: this is a wrong use of this site. Moreover your tags are inadequate: only one tag is convenient: "vectors".

Comment: Yes, I had to duplicate it. because nobody answered my question if it was wrong or right.

Comment: But in the second post I received the answer I wanted to know.
=D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the angle between the $x-$ and $y-$ axes is $90º$, then a vector that makes equal angles is going to be at an angle of $45º$.

We can represent this in the polar coordinate system as a point with $\theta = 45º, r = 1$, where $\theta$ is the angle from the x-axis, and $r$ is the distance from the origin.

You can convert this into Cartesian form with the formula $x = \cos \theta, y = \sin \theta$, which will give you the position vector of the line.

Comment: Thank you very much....
=D

Comment: @Juan Carlos Trujillo No problem! Don't forget you can accept an answer - click the green arrow below the vote arrows to do so...