# The vector A whose magnitude is 1.72 units makes equal angles with the coordinates axes. Find Ax,Ay,Az

Tags: calculus, physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

I have just done the problem but at the moment when I apply Pythagoras the magnitude comes out wrong, but it should be right. I did it with polar coordinates and then turned it into Cartesian coordinates.

[image]

Now here I just applied Pythagoras, equalling the magnitude and the answer seems to be right, but if I apply that result into the prior it gives me something different.

WHY AREN'T THESE RESULTS EQUAL?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you set $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 45^\circ$? That is incorrect. The vector does not lie in any of $xy$, $yz$, and $zx$ planes. The correct answer is $A_x = A_y = A_z = 1$.

Comment: So, In this case can't I put the degrees the same?

Comment: $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$. But they are not equal to $45^\circ$.

Comment: I set it because the statement says that the angles are the same. and it is just valid when is 45 degrees .

I just based this problem on this  question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407164/how-do-i-calculate-the-components-of-a-unit-vector-that-lies-in-the-xy-plane-and

Comment: If a vector lies in the xy-plane and makes equal angles with both axes then you can say $\alpha = \beta = 45^\circ$. In this case, the vector does not lie in the xy-plane or yz-plane or zx-plane.

Comment: Oh thank you again...

Comment: @JuanCarlosTrujillo Just as a comment, but be careful when you mix exact numbers with approximations. While close, yet $\,1.732 / \sqrt{3} = 0.99997\dots \ne 1\,$.

Comment: Ok, I will take this into account.
Thanks for your suggestion.  =)

Answer (score 1):

The results are different because you took the liberty to claim that the angle was $45^\circ$. Whereas the angle must be $\cos \frac{-1}{\sqrt3}\simeq54^\circ$ (approx). Which can be found by the given data.

Since,

1. $A_x=A_y=A_z=0.999 \ $ & $ \ A_x=A.\cos(a)=0.999\simeq1$ (approx)

Also,

2. Let $A=1.732=\sqrt3$

Thus we have,

3. $\cos(a)=\frac{A_x}{A}=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$ ; $a\simeq54^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by taking all the angles equal by taking generalized form and not the numerical numbers

[image]